# SharePoint 2010 July 2014 CU

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I installed July 2014 CU on my SharePoint 2010 farm .

According to the lists available on the internet the build version for this CU is 14.0.7128.5001

After installation and executing the `psconfig` wizard in my central administration  the Configuration database version is showing  14.0.7128.5000 . Shouldn't it be showing  14.0.7128.5001 instead?

Have I done something wrong?

Comment: do you have office web apps?

Comment: no its not configured on the farm

Comment: which page is showing this?

Comment: this is the page number :/_admin/FarmServers.aspx

Comment: have you do iisreset, clear configuration cache http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jamesway/archive/2011/05/23/sharepoint-2010-clearing-the-configuration-cache.aspx?Redirected=true.

Comment: Look at this: Stefan GoBner tells you not to trust that number: http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2014/08/19/sharepoint-patching-demystified.aspx